# Saving data from text file to data structures in C

Tags: c

I have this text file with various records, each record has 4 fields, 3 strings of words and one number, for example

```
field one; field two; field three; 1
field one; field two; field three; 2
```

I need to sort those records according to the last number through an insertion sort algorithm, so the second record should be the first one in the list, since 2>1. To do that, i first need to store each record before comparing them, i'm having some problems with that.

I got this until now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 100

struct Element
   {
    char one[100];
    char two[100];
    char three[100];
    int st;
   };



int main() {

    int i;
    struct Element elements[MAXLEN];


    FILE * fpointer = fopen("clients.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++) {
       struct Element *e = elements+i;  // pointer on ith element
       fscanf(fpointer, "%99s%99s%99s%d", e->one, e->two, e->three, &e->st);
    }

    printf("%s%s%s%d", elements->one, elements->two, elements->three, elements->&st);

    fclose(fpointer);
    return 0;

}
```

My current problems:

1) this current program is not good for saving string of words. It's good when the record is like: string; string; string; 1 but it won't work with phrases (like in the first example).

2) I don't really understand the structure of this: i know that i'm saving each record in my array of data structures but i'm having some problems printing each record. Let's say i want to print the second record, how can i do that? In my current work i printed `one, two, three and st` but this way, it will only print the first record.

Comment: Are your fields separated by semicolons as your example input suggests?

Comment: Yes @ChrisTurner!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210992/reading-data-from-csv-file-into-struct-getting-errors-back

Comment: It's similar to my problem, i'm looking into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `%s` when calling any of the `scanf` functions just reads in text up to the next bit of whitespace, so will work fine if you have single words in your fields, but as you've discovered falls over if there phrases. It also will read in the delimiters into your strings too, which I doubt you want.

Instead, a better solution would be to read in the entire line into a string and parse your way through it. The following bit of code reads in a line of text with `fgets` and then uses `strtok` to split it up into chunks separated by semicolons. It keeps track of how which field it is populating using `field_number` so if you add more fields, it's easy to expand. And if there are less fields than expected it will stop and move onto the next line.

```
char buffer[1024]; // Define a really big string to hold the line of text in
char *field;
int field_number;

while(fgets(buffer,1024,fpointer))
    {
    field_number=0;
    field=strtok(buffer,";");
    while(field)
        {
        switch(field_number)
            {
        case 0:
            strcpy(elements[i].one,field);
        break;
        case 1:
            strcpy(elements[i].two,field);
        break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(elements[i].three,field);
        break;
        case 3:
            elements[i].st=atoi(field);
        break;
            }
        field=strtok(NULL,";"); // Get next field
        field_number++;
        }
    i++; // Move the index for elements to the next one
    }
```

In answer to your second question, `elements` is an array. If you do `elements->one` that is the same as doing `elements[0].one`. If you want to access the second element in your array, you'd do `elements[1].one` or `(elements+1)->one` which is what you're doing with this odd line in your original code:

```
   struct Element *e = elements+i;  // pointer on ith element
```

when really you should have been using `elements[i]` as that is a lot easier to read.

Comment: So basically, here you are storing the whole content of the file on buffer, then you are parsing buffer and from that the data is stored into the data structures array?

Comment: No, not the whole file - `fgets` will read in at most one line at a time.

Comment: One last thing: i need to sort the whole record according to the last number, which is the variable st. I don't understand whether or not st is an array, and can i loop through it to sort it?

Comment: That'd be a whole new question, although one that has been asked many times before - just search for `qsort`

Comment: I'll search for it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%[^;]` in `fscanf`. `fscanf` will read the string until reaches `;`.
And use `;` as delimiter for `fscanf`. 
Your code will look like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 3

struct Element
   {
    char one[100];
    char two[100];
    char three[100];
    int st;
   };



int main() {

    int i;
    struct Element elements[MAXLEN];


    FILE * fpointer = fopen("clients.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++) {
       struct Element *e = elements+i;  // pointer on ith element
       if (fscanf(fpointer, "%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%d", e->one, e->two, e->three, &e->st) !=3)
            break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++) {
       struct Element *e = elements+i;  // pointer on ith element
    printf("%s%s%s%d\n", elements->one, elements->two, elements->three, elements->st);
}
    fclose(fpointer);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have pretty much reached the answer to your second question.

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++) {
    struct Element *e = elements+i;  // pointer on ith element
    printf("%s%s%s%d", e->one, e->two, e->three, e->&st);    
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the form `elements[i].one` to access element `one` in the i'th element.

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for! My problem was, indeed, accessing elements array!